# (W)CDMA, any repeating information?

Tags: signal, digital-communications, mobile, digital-modulation, spread-spectrum

I am looking to characterize a WCDMA channel to study the effects of multi-path. In order to do this I need to be able to find some repeating information (bit sequence) being transmitted by a station. I don't have access to the spreading codes used by the station. 
Is there any such information/bit-sequence in the CDMA/WCDMA/UMTS specification which by its nature is repeatedly transmitted? The CDMA sync-channel-message looks interesting to do this but I don't know enough about the system-architechture to say this for certain.
For example in the link there is mention of the 'Base Station Protocol Revision' being transmitted; will the bit sequence for this remain the same over time?

http://www.teletopix.org/cdma/what-is-inside-sync-channel-message-in-cdma/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are transmitting digital data, your receiver can recover the signal perfectly (or at least detect errors) and analyze the received signal in comparison to a "perfect" transmission of the same data.

Good spectrum analyzers will offer that as a ready-made analysis function.

Comment: question edited for clarity. I am trying to tap into CDMA transmitters I have no control of.

Comment: @zoulzubazz, yes, that method still works. The spreading codes are standardized.